# How do I install boot manager?

Tags: boot

How can I install boot-manager to ubuntu 12.04? I have tried sudo apt-get install boot-manager but it does not work.

Why I want is because I will close some startup application in order to optimize system performance.

EDIT:

```
error:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package boot-manager
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running these commands in a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) should do it for you:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bum
```

When trying to find a package like that, it helps to use the [Synaptic Package Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto). When I searched 'boot-manager' in it, the 'bum' package came up.

Comment: Instead of Synaptic to find packages, you can also use `apt-cache search boot-manager`... no sudo required. And you can do `apt-cache show bum` to show details about the package. That is, if you're terminal addicted.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install bum
```

try to use this command.